# How do i clean up all user installed packages in my system level python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python

I'd like to remove all packages created by sudo pip method and keep my virtualenvs intact.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Not 100% sure on that, but I think if you just deactivate that venv and pip-uninstall everything that should work.